# Invalid Index on data lookup on multiple vault auth backend

Tags: terraform, hashicorp-vault

I am writing a terraform module creates a single entity with multiple aliases. I'm an unable to lookup aliases auth backend. am I missing something. Any help greatly appreciated.

```
data "vault_auth_backend" "b" {
  provider = vault.this
  for_each = {
    for alias in var.entity.aliases :
    alias.type => alias
  }
  path = each.value.auth_path
}
```

```
resource "vault_identity_entity_alias" "alias" {
  provider = vault.this

  for_each = {
    for alias in var.entity.aliases :
    alias.name => alias
  }

  name           = each.key
  mount_accessor = lookup(data.vault_auth_backend.b[each.key], "accessor", null)
  canonical_id   = vault_identity_entity.entity.id
}
```

Terraform Plan output:

```
Error: Invalid index

  on .terraform/modules/vault_dba_entity/main.tf line 31, in resource "vault_identity_entity_alias" "alias":
  31:   mount_accessor = lookup(data.vault_auth_backend.b[each.key], "accessor", null)
    |----------------
    | data.vault_auth_backend.b is object with 2 attributes
    | each.key is "ldap-team-foo"

The given key does not identify an element in this collection value.


Error: Invalid index

  on .terraform/modules/vault_dba_entity/main.tf line 31, in resource "vault_identity_entity_alias" "alias":
  31:   mount_accessor = lookup(data.vault_auth_backend.b[each.key], "accessor", null)
    |----------------
    | data.vault_auth_backend.b is object with 2 attributes
    | each.key is "aws-team-foo"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `for_each` blocks are not the same: in the `vault_auth_backend` you are using the `type` of the alias as the key, while in the `vault_identity_entity_alias` you are using its `name`. Then you try to look up in the `vault_auth_backend` using the name, which won't work because that uses `type` for its key.

Change the `vault_auth_backend` to use `alias.name => alias` instead of `alias.type => alias`.

Comment: Thank you! I'm able to generate the `plan`

Comment: Glad to have helped. If this solves your problem, please click on the tick to the left of this answer to mark it as accepted.